# How do I prevent creating duplicate methods for member variables?

Tags: java, refactoring

### Duplicate methods for simular fields

I'm in the progress of making a little game which has a number of resources and I was thinking of one class called "ResourceManager" to take care of the needed actions on these member variables. What I've come to realize though is that the way I've implemented it causes alot of simular code and it's bugging me.

```
public class ResourceManager{
    private float resourceA = 0;
    private float resourceB = 0;
    private float resourceC = 0;

    public enum ResouceType{
        A,B,C
    }

    public void add(ResourceType type,float amount){
        switch(type){
        case ResourceType.A: resourceA += amount;
             break;
        case ResourceType.B: resourceB += amount;
             break;
        case ResourceType.C: resourceC += amount;
             break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is part of the code I have and This doesn't bother me, but I'm also adding in subtract, multiply, devide . . . And now I have this switch statement, that only determins which membervariable to alter, in every method. Since this feels like one functionality which I use in all of my methods I was wondering if there would be a way to isolate this into it's own method and than simply call that.

I've though of ways to fix this but I always end up making things more difficult or end up having the duplicate code spread over multiple classes, which is not realy an improvement. Big thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you really want a `Map<ResourceType, Float>` instead of three variables.

Comment: Hadn't thougth of that yet. Than I would just look up the Float using the ResourceType in the map and alter that one. Thanks! I'll give it a try right away!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the values in a `Map`:

```
final Map<ResourceType, Float> resources;

public ResourceManager() {
    this.resources = new EnumMap<>(ResourceType.class);
    for (ResourceType r : ResourceType.values()) {
        resources.put(r, 0f);
    }
}

public enum ResourceType {
    A,B,C
}

public void add(ResourceType type, float amount) {
    resources.merge(type, amount, Float::sum);
}
```

---

Alternatively you could add a method for getting and setting the value to the enum:

```
public class ResourceManager {

    private float resourceA = 0;
    private float resourceB = 0;
    private float resourceC = 0;

    public enum ResourceType {

        A {

            @Override
            protected void setResource(ResourceManager manager, float newValue) {
                manager.resourceA = newValue;
            }

            @Override
            protected float getResource(ResourceManager manager) {
                return manager.resourceA;
            }
        }, B {

            @Override
            protected void setResource(ResourceManager manager, float newValue) {
                manager.resourceB = newValue;
            }

            @Override
            protected float getResource(ResourceManager manager) {
                return manager.resourceB;
            }
        }, C {

            @Override
            protected void setResource(ResourceManager manager, float newValue) {
                manager.resourceC = newValue;
            }

            @Override
            protected float getResource(ResourceManager manager) {
                return manager.resourceC;
            }
        };

        protected abstract void setResource(ResourceManager manager, float newValue);

        protected abstract float getResource(ResourceManager manager);
    }

    public void add(ResourceType type, float amount) {
        type.setResource(this, type.getResource(this) + amount);
    }

    public void multiply(ResourceType type, float amount) {
        type.setResource(this, type.getResource(this) * amount);
    }
}
```